# ` pyenv install --list`で3.6.8が表示されないのはなぜしょうか？

Tags: python, pyenv

## 環境

- pyenv 1.2.8
- Xubuntu 18.04

## やりたいこと

pyenvでPython 3.6.8をインストールしたいです。
Python 3.6.8は2018/12/24にリリースされました。
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/

## 実施したこと

`pyenv install --list`を実行したところ、3.6.7はありましたが、3.6.8はありませんでした。
したがって3.6.8のインストールを諦め、3.6.7をインストールしました。

```
$ pyenv install --list
Available versions:
~ 省略 ~
  3.6.0
  3.6-dev
  3.6.1
  3.6.2
  3.6.3
  3.6.4
  3.6.5
  3.6.6
  3.6.7
  3.7.0
  3.7-dev
  3.7.1
  3.8-dev
```

## 質問

`pyenv install --list`にはなぜ3.6.8が表示されていないのでしょうか？
また、3.6.8を表示させるには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: pyenv を 1.2.9 以上にすれば良いのでは？ [pyenv/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: 解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のプラグインでpyenv 1.2.8-83-g2350e57b にアップデートしたら、`pyenv install --list`に3.6.8が表示されるようになりました。

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-update

[kunif](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif)さんのコメントを参考にしました。